# input field value attribute wont change unless type="hidden"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to maintain a input field to keep a variable which does not need to display at the front-end.
So I created an input filed like below.

html

```
<input id="id"  value=""  class="hide-element" />
```

css

```
.hide-element{
display: none;  }
```

and in javaScript I change the value by doing below.

```
$('#id').val("Hello");
```

But when I use **Google chrome's inspect element** it shows that the `value attribute is not changed`.

```
<input id="offSet" value="" class="hide-element">
```

but when I remove the css and use as below.

```
<input id="offSet"  value=""  type="hidden"/>
```

and then I call

```
$('#offSet').val("Hello");
```

Now it will show

```
<input id="offSet" value="Hello" type="hidden">
```

And ***in both cases I can view that value*** by using below though it is not showed in the first case.

```
alert($('#offSet').val());
```

Why is this kind of behavior happens ?

Comment: I could see the alert in both case:) http://jsfiddle.net/kLsy9rnd/ it just matters that you won't see the value when you inspect but is set as value though...

Comment: If you want to hide an element that can store value use type hidden as you last mentioned.

Comment: the behaviour is exactly as you describe. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the value **attribute** describes the **default** value, not the **current** value (which you can access through the value **property** (which is what `val()` does)).

Hidden inputs aren't user editable, so you may find that the default and current values are the same for them.

Answer (score -1):

If you are changing the value using .val(), wont be able to see the changes in google inspect because .val() return the current value first before it finishing operation.

If you are changing value using .attr(value) you can able to see the changes in google inspect